# Error while installation of mariadb 10 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, mysql, mariadb

When I tried to install [mariadb](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=dotsrc&distro=Ubuntu) on Ubuntu 14.04, it shows:

```
dpkg: error processing archive 
/var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_10.0.14+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
libmysqlclient18:amd64 10.0.14+maria-1~trusty 
(Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable
with libmysqlclient18 which has multiple installed instances 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried many ways to solve it but no one solved it.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/binary-packages/installing-mariadb-deb-files/#comment_949 seems the way to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

[From comments in the mariadb documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/binary-packages/installing-mariadb-deb-files/#comment_949):

To fix the "libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.34+maria-1~saucy (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libmysqlclient18 which has multiple installed instances" problem follow further steps:

> The problem is that libmysqlclient18:i386 was not fully removed by the automated install. Rather than "messing" with /var/lib/dpkg/status, my solution was:
>
> - fully remove `libmariadbclient18` (because it depends on libmysqlclient18) with `apt-get --purge remove libmariadbclient18`
> - fully remove `libmysqlclient18:i386` with `apt-get --purge remove libmysqlclient18:i386`
>
> Then proceed with the automated Software Update installation (or install `libmariadbclient18` and `libmysqlclient18 5.5.34+maria-1saucy` from the terminal)

Answer (score 3):

For those in Ubuntu 14.10 upgrading from MySQL to Maria DB, I would find this as one answer from Google searches. I would get stuck in 14.10 also with a similar

```
 libmysqlclient18:amd64 10.0.16+maria-1~utopic (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with libmysqlclient18 which has multiple installed instances
```

After following these suggestions to no avail, the following helped me greatly: [How to Replace MySQL with MariaDB in Ubuntu Server](https://journalxtra.com/web-development/apache/replace-mysql-mariadb-ubuntu-server/) by JournalXtra .

Editing /var/lib/dpkg/status and removing the two instances of libmysqlclient18 like this:

```
Package: libmysqlclient18
Status: deinstall ok config-files
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 3392
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Multi-Arch: same
Source: mysql-5.5
Version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu1
Config-Version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu1
Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.40-0ubuntu1), libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
Description: MySQL database client library
 MySQL is a fast, stable and true multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database
 server. SQL (Structured Query Language) is the most popular database query
 language in the world. The main goals of MySQL are speed, robustness and
 ease of use.
 .      
 This package includes the client library.
Homepage: http://dev.mysql.com/
Original-Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

Allowed me to install MariaDB smoothly afterward.

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

**Note**: I did get here after many attempts at this removing libmariadbclient18 and libmysqlclient18 before this solution worked.  I couldn't get past apt-get issues until these two were removed since they were reported as broken packages before I could attempt any other repair.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
sudo dpkg --purge libmysqlclient18  
sudo dpkg --purge libmysqlclient18:i386
sudo apt install -f
```